# Java duda con equals() y con ==

Tags: java, string, operador

Hasta hace unos año si yo hacia en Java

> "Hola" == "Hola"

me daba como resultado falso, hoy vi un codigo en el que lo usaban con el JDK 10 y por curiosidad fui a comprobarlo, y efectivamente devuelve verdadero, alguien me puede explicar porque pasa esto si es por la version de Java o por alguna otra cosa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porque son el mismo objeto.

Al arrancar la JVM y cargar las clases, los literales String ("hola") se reúsan allí donde aparezcan, así que con:

```
String s1 = "Hola";
String s2 = "Hola";
String s3 = new String("Hola");
```

, `s1` y `s2` apuntan a la misma instancia (definida por el compilador), y por eso `s1 == s2` devuelve `true`.

En cambio, `s3` es una instancia diferente, así que `s1 == s3` devuelve `false`.

Para completar la respuesta, la clase `String` incluye un *pool* interno donde se "cachean" strings a reusar. Todos los literales se guardan allí, y con el método [`String.intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) puedes acceder a la instancia de un String que se ha usado para los literales. Así que `s1 == s3.intern()` devuelve `true`.