# Problema con Scanner (Creo !!! )

Tags: java

Estoy realizando ejercicio de Java que en la función reservar asiento, pregunta por la fila y el asiento a través de la función reservarAsiento.

Desde ahí envío los datos de teclado y el array, que abajo expongo, a la función **obtenerPosicionPorFilaAsientos(avio, filaStr, asientoEleccion);**

Resulta que haciendo un debug se salta la línea **System.out.println("la fila " + fila + " y el asiento " + asiento + " estan en la posición " + i);** del **métedo obtenerPosicionPorFilaAsientos**, eso ocurre cuando las variables **filaStr, asientoEleccion** son recogidas a través del menú de la función reservarAsiento.

```
if ((fila == avion[i][1]) && (asiento == avion[i][2])) {
    System.out.println("la fila " + fila + " y el asiento " + asiento + " estan en la posición " + i);
    posicion = i;   
}
```

Sin embargo si a esas variables les doy el valor desde el código

```
filaStr = "2";
asientoEleccion = "B";
obtenerPosicionPorFilaAsientos(avio, filaStr, asientoEleccion)
```

o obtenerPosicionPorFilaAsientos(avio, "2","B");

funciona correctamente.

Creo que el problema está en los scanner, pero no se donde puede estar el problema.

Todos los valores son enviados como String.

```
String[][] avion = {
    {"1", "1", "A", "45821635K"},
    {"1", "1", "B", "45821635K"},
    {"1", "1", "C", "45821635K"},
    {"1", "1", "D", "45821635K"},
    {"1", "2", "A", ""},
    {"1", "2", "B", ""}
};

void reservarAsiento(String[][] avio) {
    int filaEleccion = 0;
    String asientoEleccion = "";
    String filaStr = ""; 
    Scanner fila = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner asiento = new Scanner(System.in);

    int posicio;

    System.out.println("RESERVAR ASIENTO");
    System.out.println("################");
    System.out.print("Elija la fila del avión del 1-11:");

    try {
        filaEleccion = fila.nextInt();

        if ((filaEleccion < 1) || (filaEleccion > 11)) {
            System.out.println("Es mayor de 11 y menor que 1");
            reservarAsiento(avion);
        } else if ((filaEleccion > 1) || (filaEleccion < 11)) {
            System.out.println("correcto " + filaEleccion);
            filaStr = String.valueOf(filaEleccion);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Has de introducir un número");
            fila.next();                
        }
    }  catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Has de introducir un número");
        fila.next();
    }

    System.out.print("Elija el Asiento del A-D:");
    asientoEleccion = asiento.nextLine();

    System.out.println(filaStr + " " + asientoEleccion);
    //Obteniendo la posición de la fila
    posicion = obtenerPosicionPorFilaAsientos(avio, filaStr, asientoEleccion);
    System.out.println("posición :" + posicion);
}

int obtenerPosicionPorFilaAsientos(String[][] avion, String fila, String asientos) {
    int posicion = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < avion.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < avion[i].length; j = j + NUMERO_ASIENTOS_POR_FILA) {
            if ((fila == avion[i][1]) && (asiento == avion[i][2])) {
                System.out.println("la fila " + fila + " y el asiento " + asiento + " estan en la posición " + i);
                posicion = i;
            }
        }
    }

    if (posicion == 0) {
        return FILA_INEXISTENTE;
    } else {
        return posicion;
    }
}
```

Se agradecería si alguien me pudiera echar una mano con esto.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: busca sobre comparacion de strings en java dentro del sitio.. asi no se comparan.... por eso tenes problemas...

Comment: Para comparar cadenas debes usar la función equals() no el operador == , ejemplo: if ((fila.equals(avion[i][1])) && (asiento.equals(avion[i][2]))) {

Comment: Hola me ha servido de ayuda. Estoy todos los días con PHP y al ver que pintaba los datos supuse que funcionaba. Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Java duda con equals() y con ==](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195178/java-duda-con-equals-y-con)